# Laravel 6 - Resource links prefixed with http instead of https

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I created a simple `User` resource class, using `artisan make:resource`. I uploaded my website to a production environment, and changed the `.env` file accordingly, and `APP_URL` is now including `https`. But when I make an ajax request in order to get this resource (through a proper controller of course, and with data retrieved from the database), the links attached to it (meta, links) are prefixed with `http`. That's starting to make a trouble since ajax requests from `https` to `http` resulting `blocked:mixed-content` error in the browser. How can I force resource to return links prefixed with `https`? Why isn't it happens automatically?

Comment: `the links attached to it` - what does that mean?  `when I make an ajax request` - how are you making that AJAX request?  Show us the code you are using.  Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Show us a sample of how you are assigning the data in your Resource, are you using `asset()`, `url()`, or something else? As by default a Resource uses the model's `toArray()` method.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Where you are using pagination, Laravel generates links for you, that contains the next/previous page and more. See here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#pagination

Comment: @Azeame see comment above.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thank you very much! Actually, just when you asked me what links am I talking about, I realized that they appear only when using pagination. Before you asked, I never tried to add "pagination" to my google search.

Comment: Glad you solved it.  There's a famous process of [explaining the problem to a duck](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/).  It's a good habit to get into before or as you are writing up a question - you might solve the problem before you actually post it. Even if not, it should be easy for others to help without needing further input.  Anyway, I suggest closing this as a dup of the linked question, if that was the answer.